# AWS EC2 NGINX Node server - How to use Https instead of Http

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elb

I want to change from HTTP and use HTTPS for nodejs services using nginx, I have created self-signed certificate

Now, I want to Change From

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:3000
```

To

```
https://xx.xx.xx.xxx:3000
```

How to implement this in AWS with EC2 Instance, NGINX or ELB?

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable port 443 with the certificate (ACM or LetsEncrypt), along with Port 3000.
2. Add this below code above the `server` block in nginx configuration:

> ```
>  server {
>        listen 3000;
>        if ( $http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https' ) {
>        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
>        }
>  }
> ```

3. Restart nginx.
4. Test

The request will hit the nginx on port 3000 and will redirect it to port 443.

This is untested but works for me on port 80 and 443 combination.

Comment: What about `listen`?, shall we keep it `80`?

Comment: Can you give some reference sites? or examples using ACM.